# Converting dat into a Linked List

Tags: java, file, singly-linked-list

I have an assignment where I have to read a data file containing student names and their GPAs, and put it into a linked list in ascending order. I've been struggling with the Linked List conceptually, and I've gotten to a point where I'm utterly lost. I'm not quite sure how to put the information I'm getting off of the file into a linked list. We can't use any of the built-in collection classes either, which makes it a bit more difficult.

```
public class Driver {
    private LinkedList<Student> myList;
    String name;
    double doub;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Driver();
    }
    public Driver() {
        myList = new LinkedList<Student>();
        FileInputStream file;
        
        Student x = new Student(name, doub);
        int count = 0;
try {
            file = new FileInputStream("Student.dat");
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
            String lineRead;
            while ((lineRead = read.readLine()) != null) {
                count++;
                x = new Student(lineRead,count);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I also have the "Student" class here.

```
public class Student<E> {
    private String name;
    private double gpa;
    private E value;
    private Student nextNode;
    
    
    public Student(String name, double gpa) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
    public Student(E x) {
           value = x;
    }
    
    public Student getNext() {
        return nextNode;
    }
    
    public E getValue() {
            return value;
    }
        
    public void setValue(E x) {
            value = x;
    }
    
    public void setNext(Student next) {
            nextNode = next;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public double getGPA() {
        return this.gpa;
    }
```

The data file also reads as

```
Emily   2.5
Evan    3.8
Lily    4.0
April   1.9
```

I've done some testing to try and figure out what is going on, mostly just adding methods to see what they put out and working it from there. For example I know that, If I were to put run "System.out.println(x.getGPA());" in the try catch, it would return the following

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
```

Which makes sense because I'm assuming its just reading the count instead of the numbers in the data file. If I were to run "Sysetm.out.println(x.getName());" in the try catch, it would return the following

```
Emily   2.5
Evan    3.8
Lily    4.0
April   1.9
```

This is almost correct, but If I run something like "System.out.println(myList);" I would just get

```
LinkedList@7852e922
LinkedList@7852e922
LinkedList@7852e922
LinkedList@7852e922
```

And I am 90% sure those are all null. Moving forward from that running "System.out.println(x);" returns this

```
Student@7852e922
Student@4e25154f
Student@70dea4e
Student@5c647e05
```

I think I've completely overthought this problem. There are a few other parts to the assignment, but I think if I can at least get this working I'll be set to move forward.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: How do I convert information from a data file into a singly linked list?

Comment: Break down the problem into smaller parts. What does each line in the file represent? I assume it's the name and GPA of a student, right? So you **convert each line into a Student object**. Then you add each student to the list.

Comment: One problem here: your `Student` class appears to do two different things: 1. Stores the name and GPA for a student. 2. Stores a value and "nextNode" for a node in a linked list. This should be two separate classes. Each class should only represent a single idea in your code, not two or more ideas.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you mean about the Student Class being two separate things. So Student is the data value, while I could create a class called "Node" that manages the actual node portions of the Linked List. Essentially I could leave the getName and getGPA portions, and use the rest to create that Node class. I'll do that and get back to figuring out how to convert each line into an object.

Comment: Yes, exactly! And your LinkedList class can manage the nodes.

Comment: I do have a LinkedList class set up, its very very messy, right now I'm just trying to create a .add() method that will sort itself as it adds, if not already contained in the list which is tricky.

Comment: "I'm just trying to create a .add() method that will sort itself as it adds, if not already contained in the list which is tricky." Is this a requirement for your assignment? I think you should do something simpler first: just add a new node at the head of the list. Most LinkedList implementations don't sort automatically. The ones I'm familiar with take two arguments: the data to insert and an index where it should be inserted. But your homework assignment might have different requirements than that.